# firebase security rule allow write permissions to only some specific fields/properties of my documents

Tags: firebase, permissions, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My user login system will automatically create a new document in the database collection when somebody signs up with a new phone number.

The creation and updating of user document is done through the client side JavaScript and I am using the firestore security rules for preventing a basic user from writing or modifying document properties like **isActivated** and **isAdmin**. It will work with below rule:

```
allow write: if request.response.data.isActive==null || request.response.data.isActive == response.data.isActive &&
request.response.data.isAdmin==null || request.response.data.isAdmin == response.data.isAdmin;
```

But still some hacker guys can easily modify the `dbRef.add()` function on the client side and add useless data like `{age: "hacker won't tell ya", hackersName: "Naah!", foo: "bar", bar: "foo"}` and so on.

I want the user document to hold only the properties `name, phone_number, isActive, isAdmin, FCMtoken` and nothing else. Did anybody else fall into the same trouble?
and any idea for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assert that a resource only has a certain list of keys, you can use [`rules.List#hasOnly()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List.html#hasOnly) which will evaluate to false if a value appears that is not in the given list.

```
request.response.data.keys().hasOnly(['name', 'phone_number', 'isActive', 'isAdmin', 'FCMtoken'])
```

Combining this with your other (fixed) restrictions, gives:

```
allow write: if (request.response.data.isActive == null || request.response.data.isActive == response.data.isActive)
             && (request.response.data.isAdmin == null || request.response.data.isAdmin == response.data.isAdmin)
             && request.response.data.keys().hasOnly(['name', 'phone_number', 'isActive', 'isAdmin', 'FCMtoken']);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response with the correct and non-confusing answer.